# Date Time Series wise grouping of data and distribution

Tags: python, file, datetime, pandas

I am trying the merge the datetime series with a repository data while grouping by name and summing the values.

```
File1.csv 

Timeseries,Name,count
07/03/2015 06:00:00,Paris,100
07/03/2015 06:00:00,Paris,600
07/03/2015 06:00:00,Paris,700
07/03/2015 06:00:00,London,200
07/03/2015 06:00:00,London,100
07/03/2015 06:00:00,London,500
07/03/2015 06:00:00,Dublin,300
07/03/2015 06:00:00,Dublin,400
07/03/2015 06:00:00,Dublin,400
```

Output

```
Master_file.csv (append mode)

    Name,Timeseries(n-1)Timeseries(n)#put the datetime series as header and put       
    Paris,300,1400      #Sum of all the values with same Name
    London,200,800
    Dublin,400,1100

Program 

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/home/lat_lon1.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/lat_lon_master.csv')


gp = df.groupby('Name')['date timeseries'].sum().reset_index() 
df1.merge(gp, on='Name')
```

I am having trouble in changing the `date time` column to header and putting the correct values under. Those `Names` not found can be given NAN and replaced in next iterations.

Comment: It's unclear what you're attempting here, firstly your column is named 'Date Time', additionally it's dtype will be `str` as you've not told `read_csv` that it should attempt to parse it as a datetime, thirdly you can only call `sum` on numeric and `str` dtypes so what are you expecting the output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the python pandas Data Frame documentation
[Click here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)
Here is the code you are looking at.

> Output
>
> `Timeseries    Name  count
>   07/03/2015 06:00:00  Dublin   1100
>   07/03/2015 06:00:00  London    800
>   07/03/2015 06:00:00   Paris   1400`

```
   #!/bin/python
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df=pd.read_csv('/home/saiharsh/Documents/Crowd Street/Transition_Data/Telecom_7.csv') #Please enter the file Location
    gp=df.groupby('Name').sum().reset_index()
    flag=0
    for i in gp['Name']:
        if flag==1:
            time=df['Timeseries'][df['Name']==i]
            time=time.tail(1)
            frames=[time1,time]
            time1=pd.concat(frames)
        else:
            time1=df['Timeseries'][df['Name']==i]
            time1=time1.tail(1)
            flag=1
    time1=time1.reset_index(drop=True)
    result=pd.concat([time1,gp],axis=1,join='inner')
    result=result.to_csv(index=False)
    print result
```

> `Please feel free to reply if any problem.`

Comment: Please read the question clearly. The `timeseries` has to be the header and not extra column.

Comment: For that you need to Just change one line     time1=time1.reset_index() to time1=time1.reset_index(drop=True) now no extra column will come