# Clean one column from long and big data set

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, bigdata

I am trying to clean only one column from the long and big data sets. The data has 18 columns, more than 10k+ rows about 100s of csv files, Of which I want to clean only one column.

Input fields only few from the long list

```
userLocation,   userTimezone,   Coordinates,
India,          Hawaii,    {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [73.8567, 18.5203]}
California,     USA     
          ,     New Delhi,  
Ft. Sam Houston,Mountain Time (US & Canada),{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [86.99643, 23.68088]}
Kathmandu,Nepal, Kathmandu, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [85.3248024, 27.69765658]}
```

Full input file: [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2vu8vv3sw0d25a/Turkey_28.csv?dl=0)

Code:

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = pandas.read_cvs('input.csv')

    df =  ['tweetID', 'tweetText', 'tweetRetweetCt', 'tweetFavoriteCt',       
           'tweetSource', 'tweetCreated', 'userID', 'userScreen',
           'userName', 'userCreateDt', 'userDesc', 'userFollowerCt', 
           'userFriendsCt', 'userLocation', 'userTimezone', 'Coordinates',
           'GeoEnabled', 'Language']

    df0 = ['Coordinates']
```

Other columns are to written as it is in output. After this how to go about ?

Output:

```
userLocation,   userTimezone, Coordinate_one, Coordinate_one,
India,          Hawaii,         73.8567, 18.5203
California,     USA     
          ,     New Delhi,  
Ft. Sam Houston,Mountain Time (US & Canada),86.99643, 23.68088
Kathmandu,Nepal, Kathmandu, 85.3248024, 27.69765658
```

The possible easiest suggestion or direct me to some example will be a lot helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong here.

1. The file is not a simple csv and is not being appropriately parsed by your assumed `data = pd.read_csv('input.csv')`.
2. The 'Coordinates' filed seems to be a `json` string
3. There are NaN's in that same field

This is what I've done so far.  You'll want to do some work on your own parsing this file more appropriately

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('./Turkey_28.csv')

coords = df1[['tweetID', 'Coordinates']].set_index('tweetID')['Coordinates']

coords = coords.dropna().apply(lambda x: eval(x))
coords = coords[coords.apply(type) == dict]

def get_coords(x):
    return pd.Series(x['coordinates'], index=['Coordinate_one', 'Coordinate_two'])

coords = coords.apply(get_coords)

df2 = pd.concat([coords, df1.set_index('tweetID').reindex(coords.index)], axis=1)

print df2.head(2).T

tweetID                                         714602054988275712
Coordinate_one                                             23.2745
Coordinate_two                                             56.6165
tweetText        I'm at MK Appartaments in Dobele https://t.co/...
tweetRetweetCt                                                   0
tweetFavoriteCt                                                  0
tweetSource                                             Foursquare
tweetCreated                                   2016-03-28 23:56:21
userID                                                   782541481
userScreen                                            MartinsKnops
userName                                             Martins Knops
userCreateDt                                   2012-08-26 14:24:29
userDesc         I See Them Try But They Can't Do What I Do. Be...
userFollowerCt                                                 137
userFriendsCt                                                  164
userLocation                                        DOB Till I Die
userTimezone                                            Casablanca
Coordinates      {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [23.274462...
GeoEnabled                                                    True
Language                                                        en
```

Comment: Thank you so much ..This has solved half of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

10K rows doesn't look at all like Big Data. How many columns do you have?

I don't understand your code, it is broken, but an easy example manipulation:

```
df = pd.read_cvs('input.csv')
df['tweetID'] = df['tweetID'] + 1  # add 1
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

If your data doesn't fit into memory you might consider using Dask.

Comment: Thanks fro the answer. 10K is just for one of the files. I have like more than 100 such files. 18 columns in the raw file. And I want to clean only the `coordinates` columns and in output file with all the columns from input.

Comment: You can do so iteratively. Build a list of all the files and process them one by one in a for loop.

Comment: As of now I want to properly clean one file .. for which I am facing too many setbacks :(